# reusable workflow action with multiple events - handling inputs for pull_request

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

Suppose I have two repositories, `my_project` and `my_project_tests`.

Suppose I have a shared/reusable workflow file `deploy-and-test.yml` like the following, which lives under my `my_project_tests` repo:

```yaml
on: 
    pull_request:
        types:  [opened, synchronize]
    workflow_call:
        inputs:
            github_runner:
                required: true
                type: string
            # at least one of project_hash/project_test_hash should be mandatory
            project_hash:
                required: ???
                type: string
                default: ???
            project_test_hash:
                required: ???
                type: string
                default: ???

jobs:
    deploy_and_test:
        name: Deploy my_project and run tests
        runs-on: ${{ inputs.github_runner }}
        steps:
        -   name: Deploy ephemeral environment
            uses: run_my_reusable_deploy_action
            with:
                github_runner: ${{ inputs.github_runner }}
                project_hash: ${{ inputs.project_hash }}
        -   name: Run test suite
            uses: run_my_cypress_tests
            with:
                github_runner: ${{ inputs.github_runner }}
                project_test_hash: ${{ inputs.project_test_hash }}
```

Both `run_my_reusable_deploy_action` and `run_my_cypress_tests` use the `actions/checkout@v4` action; `inputs.project_hash` and `inputs.project_test_hash` are used to specify what should be checked out in the corresponding project.

My goal is that when a PR is opened/updated in the `my_project_tests` repo, `project_test_hash` will be the git SHA for the my_project_tests PR's current commit (which will be `${{ github.ref }}`, I believe?), and `project_hash` will be determined by reading a metadata file on the current branch in the my_project_tests repo.

However, this workflow will also be triggered by pull requests under `my_project`. When this happens, I want `project_hash` to be the `my_project` PR commit hash, and `project_test_hash` determined by a metadata file in the `my_project` branch.

The ultimate goal is to ensure the versions of deployed code and test code are synchronized, without forcing the two to live within the same repository or using submodules. (I am considering having each repo list the other project as a package.json devDependency or optionalDependency instead of a checked in file, but I am worried that might cause some strange cyclical behavior).

Even better would be to only specify `ref` for the `actions/checkout` step in `run_my_reusable_deploy_action`/`run_my_cypress_tests` if it can't be inferred, but I am not sure that is possible.

Is this possible without creating an additional workflow file in `my_project_tests` that simply triggers the `deploy-and-test` action with the appropriate inputs?